# How to model/associate per-user configuration settings for third-party integrations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I am working on a project that will allow a user to integrate with third-party services. Each service will likely have their own unique set of configuration values. I'm struggling with deciding how to name and model the data that will be associated with the user.

Example data:

- **Service One**

  - base_uri: 'abc'
  - api_token: 'xyz'
- **Service Two**

  - secret_key: '123'
  - favorite_color: 'green'

I started with creating a model like `Integration::ServiceOne`, but the code started getting messy because of the namespace. I also didn't like referring to them as "ServiceOnes".

How would you name and model this data in your Rails application?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a model called `ConfigValues`:

```
belongs_to :user   
user_id:integer
service_id:integer
name:string
value:string # caveat here is you need to be careful with parsing different value types
```

and then a lookup model, `Services`

```
has_many :service_configs
service_id:integer
service_name:string
```

and perhaps a third model, something like `ServiceConfig`, that describes the possible config values for a given service:

```
belongs_to :service
variable_name
service_id
```

Then you can call stuff like `user.config_values.where(service_id: 1)`.